# Rails 4 ActiveRecord queries in custom thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Ok so I'm trying to multithread my rails application a bit but I just can't get it to work. When I make calls to ActiveRecord in a new Thread some relations results are returned empty, but when I run the same code without encompassing it in a Thread everything works fine.

My code looks something like this:

```
Class Notifier < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_users
    Thread.new do
      notifiers = Notifier.where(somethin...)
      users = User.joins(:notifiers).where(...)
      users.each do |user|
        user.update_user(...)
      end

      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
    end
  end
end
```

When this code is run and I log both "notifiers" and "users" "notifiers "contains the correct relations but not "users", "users" is empty.

How can you make queries to ActiveRecord in a custom thread?

Edit: We are running postgresql

Comment: Have you tried to recover the users with a single query?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? The problem you are probably facing is that your code executes async and your main method call is already finished.

Comment: The update user part can take several seconds to execute and there can be several calls to update_users per second. And since life must go on on the server I want to execute everything in separate threads so that I can keep processing other less frequent requests.